# Visual Basic Prevent User from Changing System Volume

Tags: vba, audio

I am currently creating a Visual Basic project which requires sound output to provide a "usable" user experience.  Is there any way I can use Visual Basic, or change Windows settings, to prevent the user from turning down the SYSTEM volume (or muting)?  I cannot find any resources that outline this explicitly.

Comment: Why should you do this? If user **doesn't want** to hear the sound why do you want to force them?... you mentioned "usability" but your request is horrible regarding usability.. so in fact you would terribly decreasing your "usability" by doing that especially when its about sound/music etc

Comment: It is not about music, it is about testing software.  In order for the test to continue correctly, the user MUST hear sounds coming from the software.  Any disabling, accidental or not, will disrupt the test.

Comment: While it may be possible to unmute or increase the volume, it will not prevent that the users switches off his speakers or use headphones but not wearing them. Maybe you can add something like a test that the user is listening (*"how many beeps where played..."*).